# Eclipse constantly loses connection to device during debugging over USB

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

While debugging my app in Eclipse, Eclipse constantly loses connection to my device connected by USB. This seems to typically occur when I attempt to view the value of variables. Any suggestions on what can be the problem? I am running the latest version of the Android SDK.

Comment: I've had the same problem for a long time. Logcat won't help you. It was a hardware problem though. Try another USB cable.

Comment: @timmied - the same in my case +1. The cable is almost always the problem.

Comment: Guess it is good enough as a real answer, almost everybody I know have encountered this problem at least once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often one of these problems:

- Your USB cable.
- Drivers

99% of the time it will be the USB cable, if this won't fix it, re-install your [drivers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)